# What is the simplest Rails file upload method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've looked at the available options and it seems like everything is optimized for image uploading as display. I just need simple file upload and retrieval. Are there any good options?

Answer (score 3):

Paperclip is a popular choice for uploading and sizing images, but you can upload any type of file with it (doc, zip, txt, pdf... anything). Highly recommended. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: You get mu upvote 4 paperclip mate. I never said paperclip's ugly, its difficult 4 newbies to debug what,s wrong with their code when uploading apps to heroku.

Answer (score 2):

I like carrierwave.  It has built in support for s3, has no workaround for setting up apps on heeroku unlike paperclip.

Comment: Paperclip also has built-in support for s3... two key/values in your model... hardly a "workaround". `:storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => '#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml'`.

Comment: Yea, it does, but my concern was the workaround involved while uploading apps on heroku

Comment: What workaround? You set Paperclip to use s3 and you're done.

Comment: You need write permissions to modify images, which heroku doesn't allow

Comment: Right, that's why you're uploading them to s3.

Comment: I think we are misunderstanding each other. I'll just give you an upvote for your Carrierwave suggestion and move along. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I use Carrierwave for mine and have been happy with it. I am just uploading general files, not specifically images.  It is easy to implement and has good advanced features if you need them later. It also integrates with Fog to make using remote storage sources (like s3 or rackspace cloud files) easy.

Answer (score 1):

Carrierwave benefits:

With carrierwave, the attachment is a seperate model instead of an attribute on an existing model, which might make things cleaner to work with.

It comes with the ability to attach a file via url (user passes in a url to a file) instead of uploading with a form).

It comes with some sort of way to remember files across form validation failures, although I've never used this and I'm not sure how it's done... maybe with two forms and ajax?

It seems to have a more engaged and enthusiastic community around it, with more projects extending it.

For S3, they use fog instead of aws-s3, and fog has much more active development.

That said, paperclip is pretty great and is actively maintained, and might come with handier default image manipulation stuff, I'm not sure.